# disable row selection in winui3 datagrid

Tags: c#, datagrid, winui-3, windows-community-toolkit, datagridrow

I have been trying very hard to disable hover, mouse over and row selections on datagrid rows. I had used the following code for Wpf application in the past and it worked perfectly. However, I am in the middle of the process of migrating my code to the new Winui3 and I just can't make it work again.

but the problem is how to hide row selections. See this picture:

[image: 1]

Here is the code that works for Wpf;

```
<controls:DataGrid.Style>
   <Style TargetType="controls:DataGridCell">
           <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
           <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
  </Style>
</controls:DataGrid.Style>
```

Now, `FocusVisualStyle` doesn't exists. I was able to disable cell borders on selection by overriding some brush resources like these:

```
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DataGridCellFocusVisualPrimaryBrush" Color="Transparent" />
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DataGridCellFocusVisualSecondaryBrush" Color="Transparent" />
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```xml
<controls:DataGrid>
    <controls:DataGrid.Resources>
        <Color x:Key="DataGridRowSelectedBackgroundColor">Transparent</Color>
        <Color x:Key="DataGridRowSelectedHoveredUnfocusedBackgroundColor">Transparent</Color>
        <Color x:Key="DataGridRowSelectedUnfocusedBackgroundColor">Transparent</Color>
        <!--
        This one is better not being just "Transparent".
        This way you won't lose visual effects for hovered selected rows.
        -->
        <StaticResource
            x:Key="DataGridRowSelectedHoveredBackgroundColor"
            ResourceKey="SystemListLowColor" />
    </controls:DataGrid.Resources>
</controls:DataGrid>
```

You can find the colors in the GitHub [repo](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/main/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid/DataGrid/DataGrid.xaml).

Comment: Not working. I have tried overriding these colors before but it didn't work.

Comment: Weird. I actually created a sample app and worked.

Comment: Looking at generics.xaml, I think some color keys need to be changed.

Comment: This color SystemListLowColor is actually the same as the one I am pointing to on the image “this one”, even changing it to any random color doesn’t change anything.

Comment: Any more thoughts about this. I can’t still get it to work.

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding your issue. In my sample code, selected rows doesn't change its color. Does my answer doesn't change anything? or doesn't change enough for your requirements?